# How to send keys to terminal buffer?

Tags: vim, neovim

I love neovim's `:term` command. When I working on Django, I open a new tab and I run these commands:

- `:term` (go to terminal)
- `source env/bin/activate` (activate virtual environment)
- `cd src` (go to project directory)
- `python3 manage.py runserver` (run debug server)

I want to automate this job.

I can run first command via typing `:term [command]`. But I want to run the above commands in a sequence.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to `:term` is a shell command; so you can use:

```
:term source env/bin/activate && cd src && python3 manage.py runserver
```

This is a lot of tying, so you can create a command:

```
:command! StartServer :term source env/bin/activate && cd src && python3 manage.py runserver
```

An alternative would be to create a shell function and run that.